# Who deployed SSIS package on SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am seeing the version of the SSIS project which got deployed yesterday and I don't remember deploying anything in production. So, is there any way to find out what user performed the deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Query the `catalog.operations` view in the SSISDB database.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM catalog.operations O 
WHERE O.operation_type <> 200 -- everything but create_execution and start_execution
ORDER BY O.start_time desc
```

ref: [catalog.operations (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-operations-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)