In SQL Server SSISDB, is there a way to log which user deployed changes to a package or project?
My team has several ETL processes that are based on an SSIS solution that gets deployed into SSISDB on SQL Server, and then run via SQL Agent Job. Multiple people have the power to edit and deploy or redeploy packages.
While one can right-click on the SSISDB project and click "versions" to see the latest deployment datetimes, is there anyway to achieve the following functionality (whether by settings or via code):

See which user (active directory is fine) made the last deployment
See whether an entire SSISDB project was re-deployed versus just one package within it

Many thanks

catalog.operations has the column caller_name which is the name of the account that performed the operation.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317254/who-deployed-ssis-package-on-sql-server-2016

In catalog.operations the operation type column would be 101 (deploy_project) if the entire project was deployed
